# Query Records by Hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a query that uses 4 joined tables. I have to create a CASE as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ActivityID, Dept, 
    MONTH(ReportDate) AS Month, YEAR(ReportDate) AS Year, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CODE1 IN ('09A', '11A', '11B', '11C', '120', '13A', '13C', '220', '23%', '240')
            THEN 'Num'
        WHEN Status = 'Active'
            THEN 'Val'
    END AS Type
```

The above `CASE` is supposed to search in the column `CODE1` for the values in parenthesis, then under the `Type` column, the string 'Num' would appear and when the column Status (a column in a join) has 'Active' as the value, the string 'Val' would appear. It seems to work okay but I am supposed to see two rows for each `ActivityID` - one that says Num and one that says Val but I only see one or the other.

As part of this query, I need to include SQL statements that will only use an `ActivityID` once based on a hierarchy rule that I have to set. So, if CODE1 has values of 09A, 11C, and 220 it would only count toward 09A and not count toward the other 2 values and I have had no success writing that part of the query.

Here is the query I have written so far. Some of the column names I have listed aren't the actual column names because of work rules:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ActivityID, Dept, 
    MONTH(ReportDate) AS Month, YEAR(ReportDate) AS Year, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CODE1 IN ('09A', '11A', '11B', '11C', '120', '13A', '13C', '220', '23%', '240')
            THEN 'Num'
        WHEN Status = 'Active'
            THEN 'Val'
    END AS Type,
    COUNT(CASE
              WHEN io.CODE1 = '09A' AND io.Att = 'false'
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE 0  
          END) AS '09A',
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN p.Status = 'Active' AND io.Code! = '09A' AND io.Att = 'false'
                THEN p.ValueAmount
                ELSE 0 
        END) AS '09A',
FROM 
    Table_I i
LEFT JOIN 
    Location lo ON i.Guid = lo.Guid
LEFT JOIN 
    Table_IO io ON lo.LocationID = io.LocationID
LEFT JOIN 
    Table_P p ON i.Guid = p.Guid
GROUP BY 
    ActivityID, Dept, ReportDate, CODE1, Att, Status
```

With the above code, I am trying to get the count of '09A' values to show under Type.Num and the sum of any integer values in ValueAmount are shown under Type.Val.

The values in CODE1 determine the hierarchy that each ActivityID would be counted only once.

Thank you in advance.

I wanted to add a visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve to see if that helps:
[Visual Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PegQS.png)

Comment: “I am supposed to see two rows for each ActivityID” — include actual structure and (*minimal*) data and expected results. From what is shown, there is no evidence that one would expect such from the query.

Comment: Sidenote - column aliases should be delimited with `[square brackets] or double quotes`, single quotes are for literals.

Comment: @user2864740 - thank you. I will be sure to do that next time.

Comment: @Stu - Thank you.

Comment: For the _first_ "09A" derived column: You'll either want to use SUM if your CASE is generating 1 or 0, since COUNT, as you've used it, just counts non-null values.  Both 0 and 1 are non-null values.  You could also change your CASE to generate 1 or null, in which case COUNT would do what you expect.  `COUNT(CASE WHEN x = y THEN 1 END)` ... or  `SUM(CASE WHEN x = y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Side point: `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` on the same query is a major code-smell. Why would you need to `DISTINCT` it if you are already grouping? And the columns you are grouping by don't seem to match what you are selecting